# How to hide VsCode Scrollbars?

Tags: visual-studio-code

It seems there used to be a setting to hide the scrollbars in VsCode:

```
"editor.scrollbar.vertical": "hidden"
```

However, it seems this was deprecated and now I get an error `Unknown configuration setting`.

Is there a new way to hide the scrollbars in VsCode?

Comment: _**Nope**_**.**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the past the setting

`"editor.scrollbar.vertical": "hidden"` would give an `Unknown configuration setting` warning in settings.json and be grayed out.  But it would nevertheless work after a reload.

As of v1.58 it appears that

```
editor.scrollbar.vertical - 'auto' | 'visible' | 'hidden'
editor.scrollbar.horizontal - 'auto' | 'visible' | 'hidden'
editor.scrollbar.verticalScrollbarSize - number
editor.scrollbar.horizontalScrollbarSize - number
editor.scrollbar.scrollByPage - boolean
```

are all being made "first-class citizens/settings` and will work without a reload or error message.

See [Expose editor scrollbar options and react to them being updated](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/127788).

From the Insiders Build now:

[image: new scrollbar settings v1.58]

---

Previous answer:

Probably the best you can do is make them transparent:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {

  "scrollbarSlider.background":"#9aa0",
  "scrollbarSlider.activeBackground": "#f000",
  "scrollbarSlider.hoverBackground": "#ff00"
}
```

There are a couple more scrollbar color properties.

Comment: I ended up needing more tweaks that weren't supported so I just added an extension to inject my own CSS.