# Make horizontal scrollbar more visible in Visual Studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code

The following screen shot is of Visual Studio code viewing a text file which is wider than the screen:

[image]

There is a horizontal scrollbar (barely) visible at the bottom of the screen. I find this difficult to see (I just spent 20 minutes searching for how to add a horizontal scrollbar because I didn't even know it was there). In fact, by default it fades to invisible if the window doesn't have focus. There is a fix for this in the following (undocumented) setting:

```
"editor.scrollbar.horizontal": "visible"
```

However, I still find this unsatisfactory. Is there any way to improve this situation? The scrollbars in Visual Studio itself are fine, for example.

(Note: I'm aware of word wrap, but that's not what I want.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can give it a more obvious color:

```
 "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    
    "scrollbarSlider.background": "#ff0000",
    "scrollbarSlider.hoverBackground": "#0088ff",

}
```

There are a couple more scrollbar color settings you can try, these affect both vertical and horizontal scrollbars though.

---

As of v1.58 see https://stackoverflow.com/a/46634103/836330 for more officially exposed scrollbar settings including

`editor.scrollbar.verticalScrollbarSize`
`editor.scrollbar.horizontalScrollbarSize`

Comment: That is a massive improvement. Thanks. Might not quite go for red... :-)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/68233096/836330 for more scrollbar options.

Answer (score 1):

```
,"editor.scrollbar.verticalScrollbarSize": 10
,"editor.scrollbar.horizontal": "visible"
,"editor.scrollbar.horizontalScrollbarSize": 15
```

[How to make scrollbars wider in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50106972/how-to-make-scrollbars-wider-in-visual-studio-code/54392013#54392013)